# Network does not work for one WSL distro but works for the other

Tags: networking, fedora, windows

I installed Debian from Microsoft Store onto my Windows 10 with WSL. Everything works.

I installed Fedora 33 following [this Fedora Magazine article](https://fedoramagazine.org/wsl-fedora-33/), it cannot reach the network.

How can I figure out what the problem is? I cannot download not even a ping to my virtual machine.

UPDATE: having WSL version 1 might be the problem

Comment: The article specifies WSL2 as a prerequisite

Answer (score 1):

Installing the latest Windows upgrade helped: now I have WSL2 and my Fedora instance accesses the network.